# Java File read and write in reverse [byte by byte]

Tags: java, stream

I need to read from this text file `source.txt` and write the content in reverse in this text file `destination.txt`. The read and write **must** be done using byte-by-byte!

I did this exercise using `BufferedReader` & `BufferedWriter` which gives you a whole line as a string then it's very simple to reverse it!

But I don't know how to write in reverse order using byte-by-byte!
Thank you for your help!

`source.txt` has this text: "Operating Systems"

And the result on `destination.txt` should be the reverse of `source.txt`: "smetsyS gnitarepO"

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = new FileInputStream("source.txt");
            out = new FileOutputStream("destination.txt");


            int c;

            while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {

                out.write(c);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what did you reverse `byte-by-byte` ?

Comment: Read the file into a byte array and then write out the byte array in the reverse order.

Comment: You are looking for `RandomAccessFile`

Comment: If your file is in ASCII, then it's pretty simple - every byte is basically the same as a char. If it's UTF-8 or other multibyte encoding, it may be a challenge. Anyway, hint: keep the bytes you read until you reach the end of a line or the end of the file.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: If what is asked for is *byte for byte* reversal, encoding does not matter, the file should be processed at a byte level as is it was binaty.

Comment: @SergeBallesta The instructions were that the **read and write** be done byte by byte, not that the content is reversed byte by byte. The content is still considered "text", so it *can't* be reversed byte by byte.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Good point!

Answer (score 3):

You can use RandomAccesFile for reading:

```
...
            in = new RandomAccessFile("source.txt", "r");
            out = new FileOutputStream("destination.txt");
            for(long p = in.length() - 1; p >= 0; p--) {
                in.seek(p);
                int b = in.read();
                out.write(b);
            }
...
```